# Attributes from another class not being appended to a list and printed

Tags: python, class, object, attributes, append

So I'm having difficulty figuring this out, I made two classes one called Course and one called Transcript.

I have a method in the Transcript class called "add_course" and it's supposed to append the courses fed to it into a list of courses called "courses" which is set as "self.courses".

The problem is that When I print the Transcript class after adding some test courses, it just prints "Transcript: " with nothing added.

```
class Course:
    def __init__(self, number, credit, grade):
        #validgrades = ['A','B','C','D','F','IP']
        #if grade not in validgrades:
            #raise CourseError("bad grade" + "'" + grade + "'" )
        self.number = number #string
        self.credit = credit #int
        self.grade = grade #string
    def __str__(self):
        return ('%s: credit %d, grade %s' % (self.number, self.credit, self.grade))
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.number==other.number and self.credit==other.credit and self.grade==other.grade
    def is_passing(self):

        if self.grade == 'F' or self.grade == 'IP':
            return False
        else:
            return True
c1 = Course("CS112",4,"A")
print(c1)
print(c1.is_passing())
c2 = Course("ENGH101", 3, "B")
print(c1==c2)
c3 = Course("MATH113", 4, "IP")

class Transcript:

    def __init__(self):
        courses = []
        self.courses = courses


    def __str__(self):
        strtrans=""
        strtrans +='Transcript:\n'
        for i in self.courses:
            strtrans+= '%s\n\t' %(i)
        return strtrans

    def __eq__(self,other):
        if self.courses == other.courses:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def add_course(self,course):
        for i in self.courses:
            self.courses.append(course)

    def course_by_number(self, number):
        for i.number in self.courses:
            if self.number == number:
                print('It worked!')
                return True
            elif self.number == None:
                return None
            else:
                return False
t=Transcript()
print(t)
t.add_course(c1)
t.add_course(c2)
t.add_course(c3)
print(t)
```

**The output is:**

CS112: credit 4, grade A

True

False

Transcript:

Transcript:

**When it SHOULD be:**

Transcript:

CS112:  credit  4,  grade   A

ENGH101:    credit  3,  grade   B

MATH113:    credit  4,  grade   IP

Comment: at a glace, your problem is probably here `self.course = self.courses.append(course)` you don't need `self.course = ` append, modifies the list, it doesn't add and return

Comment: I removed that part and it still doesn't print anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that with

```
def add_course(self,course):
    for i in self.courses:
        self.course = self.courses.append(course)
```

You are iterating over `self.courses`. When this list is empty the for loop does not run as there is nothing to iterate over. This would actually also cause an infinite loop (until you hit a MemoryError) as you are appending to the same list you are iterating over.

Another problem that you would see, which is as @Nullman described in the comments is `list.append` returns `None` so with

```
self.courses = self.courses.append(course)
```

after the first call you list is now `None`, the second time `add_course` is called, it would raise

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

So your function should just be

```
def add_course(self,course):
    self.courses.append(course)
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So because .append uses in-place modification, there is no need to iterate over the same list again and again, I can simply use the .append?

Comment: Yes, append will add the specified object to the end of the list in place.